# Принадлежность интервалу

Tags: c++

Код работает, но неправильно, не могу понять, в чем ошибка.
Вот задание:
Пусть `x0 = a; xk = qx(k–1) + b , ( k = 1, 2, ...)`. Даны неотрицательное целое `n` , действительные `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `q` (`c < d`). Принадлежит ли `xn` интервалу (`c`, `d`)?

Код:

```
#include<stdafx.h> 
#include<math.h> 
#include<cstdlib> 
#include<iostream> 


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n, k;
    float a, b, c, d, q;
    float x[100];
    {
        printf("Введіть значення n: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &n);
        printf("Введіть значення a,b,c,d,q: \n");
        scanf_s("%i  ", &a, &b, &c, &d, &q);
        x[0] = a;
        printf("x[0]= %5.1f\n", a);
        if (c > d);
        {
            printf("По умові c<d, введіть інші значення\n");

        }
        if (c < d);
        for (k = 1; k <= 8; k++)
        {
            x[k] = q*x[(k - 1)] + b;
            scanf_s("x[%3f]= %5f", k, x[k]);
        }
        if ((c <= x[n]) && (d >= x[n]));
        printf("Хn належить інтервалу (c,d)");
        else
        {
            printf("Хn не належить інтервалу (c,d)");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код болен всеми детскими болезнями - неверные спецификаторы формата, точка с запятой после `if`, да даже заголовочный файл подключен неверный... Словом, он у вас не то что не работает - компилироваться не должен :)

Вот правленый вариант, смотрите, сравнивайте, понимайте, что и почему не так, как у вас...

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n, k;
    float a, b, c, d, q;
    float x[100];
    {
        printf("Введiть значення n: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
        printf("Введiть значення a,b,c,d,q: \n");
        scanf_s("%f %f %f %f %f", &a, &b, &c, &d, &q);

        x[0] = a;
        printf("x[0]= %5.3f\n", a);

        if (c >= d);
        {
            printf("По умовi c<d, введiть iншi значення\n");
        }

        for (k = 1; k <= 8; k++)
        {
            x[k] = q * x[k - 1] + b;
            printf("x[%d]= %5.3f\n", k, x[k]);
        }

        if ((c <= x[n]) && (d >= x[n]))
        {
            printf("Хn належить iнтервалу (c,d)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Хn не належить iнтервалу (c,d)\n");
        }
    }
}
```